# JavaFX - 3 controllers, changing scenes, unable to set label text from A to B

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

My problem is rather simple.

I have 3 controllers:

- MainController
- Controller
- Controller2

I'm trying to tell inside `Controller`, that upon button press, please change the label text in `Controller1`. Using `MainController` as a middleman. Problems arise, when I'm asking it to change to the new scene while also wanting to pass on the information regarding the label.

NullPointerExecption on line 17, Controller class (`main.setLabel("abc");)`

I don't have a seperate FXML file for the `MainController`. I do however have a seperate project, where I got the code running while using `MainController` with FXML, but I had to use Tabpane and create seperate tabs, which isn't what I'm looking for.

**MainController.class**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;


public class MainController {

    @FXML Controller controller1;
    @FXML Controller2 controller2;


    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        controller1.init(this);
        controller2.init(this);
    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        System.out.println("Setting text..");
        controller2.label123.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**Controller.class**

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private MainController main;
    @FXML private Button buttonSend;

    @FXML private void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        main.setLabel("abc");
        System.out.println("Button clicked.");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        buttonSend.getScene().setRoot(root);
    }

    public void init(MainController mainController) {
        main = mainController;
    }
}
```

**Controller2.class**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller2 {

    private MainController main;

    @FXML public Label label123;

    public void init(MainController mainController) {
        main = mainController;
    }
}
```

**sample.fxml** (for Controller.class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="buttonSend" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="Button">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**sample2.fxml** (for Controller2.class)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller2">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label123" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="168.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="43.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: How do you use/combine the fxmls?

Comment: I don't combine them. They are all seperate. Each controller has their own FXML. MainController doesn't have any.

Comment: I added the FXML files. You can take a look!

Comment: How do you think `MainController.initialize` would be invoked then??? Even if it was used with a fxml, `FXMLLoader` would not be able to find this method, since it's not annotated with `@FXML`. `initialize` not being called leads to the `main` fields not being initialized which causes the NPE.

Comment: Pardon, i'm very new to Java and JavaFX. I figured something might be wrong with the initialize, since it was greyed out in the window. What would you suggest doing? Creating a @FXML for the MainController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you need to pass a instance of the `MainController` to the controllers.

In this case I'd recommend using the `MainController` as factory or creating a factory that "knows" about the `MainController`. You can pass the information about the controllers to the `MainController` instance in the `init` methods:

```
public interface InitializableController {
    public void init(MainController mainController);
}
```

```
public class MainController {

    private Controller controller1;

    public void setController1(Controller controller) {
        this.controller1 = controller;
    }

    private Controller2 controller2;

    public void setController2(Controller2 controller) {
        this.controller2 = controller;
    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        System.out.println("Setting text..");
        controller2.label123.setText(text);
    }

    public <T> T loadFXML(URL url) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
        T result = loader.load();

        // call init, if there is a controller implementing InitializableController
        Object controller = loader.getController();
        if (controller instanceof InitializableController) {
            ((InitializableController) controller).init(this);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

```
public class Controller implements InitializableController {

    ...

    @FXML private void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Button clicked.");
        Parent root = main.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        main.setLabel("abc");
        buttonSend.getScene().setRoot(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(MainController mainController) {
        main = mainController;
        mainController.setController(this);
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller2 implements InitializableController {

    // private MainController main;

    @FXML public Label label123;

    @Override
    public void init(MainController mainController) {
        // main = mainController;
        mainController.setController2(this);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to also use the `MainController.load` method to load the first fxml.

BTW: I do not recommend giving other classes direct access to the fields of one of the controllers. You could move the data to the `MainController` class as well by adding a `StringProperty` there which the `text` property of `label123` could be bound to in the `init` method. This way `MainController` does not need to know about the internals of `Controller2` and therefore is easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I got a good insight and it helped me alot following the steps you provided. :) **5/5**